# Como colocar o endereço da imagem no src sem que tem que ser um component no react

Tags: javascript, react, react-dom

Boa noite tenho um arquivo js com um array de objetos e uma dessas propriedades é imagem como eu faço para renderiza-la no src já tentei {item.image} mas é só uma string e o react aparentemente usa imagens como se fossem componentes, outro detalhe é que a propriedade de imagem desses objetos recebe uma string que é a localização dessas imagens ../assets/imagemTal.png, ele não renderiza de jeito nenhum ou busca pelo menos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gabriel, no React essas imagens locais precisam ser importadas. Você pode fazer um require dentro do componente `img` ou do seu array. Veja o que for mais fácil. Eu fiz aqui um componente bem rapidinho e deu certo, veja:

```js
return (
    <div className="App">
      {images.map(item => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <img src={require(`${item.image}`)} alt="imagem" />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

o meu array estava assim:

```js
const images = [
  {
    id: Math.random(),
    image: "./assets/article.full.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: Math.random(),
    image: "./assets/blue-flame-2.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: Math.random(),
    image: "./assets/energy-main-6.jpg"
  }
];
```

Comment: Parece que pode  funcionar, obrigado

Comment: Você pode usar o require no array ou até mesmo importar as imagens e colocar o nome do import tipo:`import { nome_que_vc_quiser } from './assets/sua_imagem.jpg';` e ai no array voce usa o nome que você colocou na imagem.

Comment: po não ta funcionando não, olha o que eu escrevi

Comment: <ul> { items.map(item => ( <li key={item.id}>                     
                <button onClick=this.handlerClick.bind(this,item)}>
                <div className="containerImage">     <img src={require(`${item.image}`)} alt="teste"/>              
                </button>
            </li>
            ))}
              )      </ul>

Comment: Manda como está seu array onde tem a imagem. Vai ficar mais fácil pra entender.

Comment: Eu consegui resolver do jeito que vc disse obrigado por isso marquei como resolvido!

Comment: Show! Qualquer coisa chama ai.

Comment: Claro! Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo bastante genérico, mas que mostra que sim, é possivel sem react.

```js
function carregarImagem() {
  var imagem = document.getElementById("imagem");
  imagem.src = "https://s2.glbimg.com/RV6Buc-U84d00Ky_aBhOiGWZeXs=/0x59:2000x1185/540x304/smart/http://i.s3.glbimg.com/v1/AUTH_59edd422c0c84a879bd37670ae4f538a/internal_photos/bs/2019/p/M/8bGAWSRuWFf6NgMwCS1w/bancoimagemfotoaudiencia-ap-408260.jpg";
}
```

```html
<img id="imagem" src="" title="Clique para carregar" width="450" height="300" onclick="carregarImagem()">
```